# Could not process parameters: int(1), it must be of type list, tuple or dict

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I am currently trying to insert two numbers into a column called konto_type_kode from a table called kontotype but i keep getting this error, here is what my code looks like:

```
import createdb
import createtables
import mysql.connector

config = mysql.connector.connect(
    host =  "localhost",
    user = "root",
    password = "root",
    database = "dbank_banksystem"
)

cursor = config.cursor()

addtype1 = """ INSERT INTO kontotype (konto_type_kode) VALUES (%i, %i)"""
addtype1val = (1,2)

cursor.executemany(addtype1,addtype1val)

config.commit()
```

Comment: Use `execute()`, not `executemany()`. You're only inserting one row.

Comment: If I do this I get the "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement" error

Comment: `%i` should be `%s`

Comment: Now unfortunately I still get the " Failed executing the operation; Could not process parameters: int(1), it must be of type list, tuple or dict" error after changing the values to %s instead, although I forgot to add that the entries im trying to add are stored as intergers.

Comment: Why would you need to add that? I can see it in the snippet you posted.

Comment: It sounds like you went back to `executemany` after you fixed `%s`.

Comment: You have two placeholders in `VALUES`, but only one column name. Are you trying to insert into 2 columns in 1 row, or 1 column in 2 rows?

Comment: I am trying to insert 2 columns in 1 row.

Comment: But you only have one column name `konto_type_code`. What column is the second value supposed to be inserted into?

Answer (score 0):

Placeholders in mysql-connector are `%s`, not `%i`.

`cursor.executemany()` requires the parameters to be a 2-dimensional sequence, a sequence of rows to add. So change `addtype1val` to be a tuple of tuples.

You should only have one placeholder in the `VALUES` list, since you're only inserting into one column. `cursor.executemany()` will repeat the `VALUES` list enough times for each row.

```
addtype1val = ((1,), (2,))

addtype1 = """ INSERT INTO kontotype (konto_type_kode) VALUES (%s)"""
addtype1val = (1,2)

cursor.executemany(addtype1,addtype1val)
```